# How Kubernetes HPA works?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, hpa

I am trying to add Horizontal Pod Autoscaling (HPA) to my Kubernetes Deployments. My application is composed by 5 microservices which are connected between them. I have one NodePort (a Traefik service) which is in charge of controlling the traffic from the outside.
The call is a HTTPS POST that sends a csv file which is processed by the application. It can be send via command line or using a web app (UI). The curl command will be like:

```
curl https://our_app_name -X POST -F "file=@test.csv"
```

The questions I have about the functionality of HPA are the following,

1. How HPA distributes the calls between the replicas? Is Kubernetes capable of parallel computing, i.e., divide the call between the replicas or each call goes to only one replica?
2. Can a replica attend more than one call at the same time?
3. In the HPA specifications, for example here:

```
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
       type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 50
```

What is this 50%? Is it 50% of the CPU of the pod or of the cluster?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Each call goes to only one replica of a pod
2. You can send as many requests to a pod via ingress/service but it will finally reach to one of the replicas of the pod
3. with `averageUtilization: 50` HorizontalPodAutoscaler would attempt to ensure that each `pod` was consuming roughly `50%` of its `requested` `CPU`. This is not CPU of the node.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answer! I have a clearer picture now. However, my question now is: what is the goal of the HPA if it each replica of the pod can't attend more than one call? I mean, in my case, I used HPA and for a call it created 3 replicas, but it is only using one so the latency is not reduced, right?

Comment: HPA just automates scaling pods based on some metrics which you would have to do manually otherwise. The load balancing between replicas of pods is still round robin via kube-proxy unless you use a ingress like nginx which can do advanced L7 load balancing

Comment: If you are getting 10 requests _per second_, and then that load increases to 30 requests _per second_, HPA will help get more pod replicas to service the increased load.  It doesn't help individual requests' latency beyond trying to manage the overall number of concurrent requests per replica.